# Rails have_selector not working when selector is in application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I hard code the following in new.html.erb just above the form_tag my test passes:

```
<div class="alert alert-error">Invalid email/password combination</div>
```

But when the div is generated using a flash.now message in application.html.erb, which yields to new.html.erb, the test fails.

--------------- application.html.erb ---------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
</head>
<body>
  <a name="top" />
  <div id="main_wrapper">
    <%= render 'layouts/leaderboard_advertisement' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div id="threecolwrap">
      <div id="twocolwrap">
        <%= render 'layouts/left_advertisement' %>
        <section id="main_content_area">
          <% flash.each do | key, value | %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
          <% end %>          
          <%= yield %>
        </section>
      </div> <!-- end of twocolwrap -->
        <%= render 'layouts/left_advertisement' %>
    </div> <!-- end of threcolwrap -->
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div> <!-- end of main_wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

--------------- new.html.erb ---------------------

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign In") %>

<div>
  <div class="pages_title1">
    <h2 class='title_text_with_logo'>Sign In</h2>
    <%= image_tag "logo1_140_22.png", class: 'title_logo title_logo_position_right' %>
  </div>  
  <div class="pages_text1 wide_column">
    <div>
      <%= form_tag(sessions_path) do %>
        <%= label :session, :email %>
        <%= text_field :session, :email %>

        <%= label :session, :password %>
        <%= password_field :session, :password %>

        <%= submit_tag "Sign in" %>
  <% end %>

      <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
    </div>
    <div class='full_logo_center'>
      <%= image_tag "fulllogo1_200_48.png" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

--------------- test.html.erb ---------------------

```
describe "signin" do
  before { visit signin_path }
  let(:page_title) { 'Sign In' }

  describe "with invalid information" do
    it { should have_selector('h2', text: 'Sign In')}
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }
  end
end
```

--------------- session_controller.rb ---------------------

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or user
  else
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your test, all you are doing is visting the "Sign In" page.  You aren't actually trying to login, so there is no error message being displayed.

The easiest way to find problems like this is to use the Capybara method `save_and_open_page` at the beginning of the test.  That way, you can see the page as Capybara sees it.  That makes mistakes in a test super obvious.  In this case, you'd see that there was no error message.

Comment: Yeah, boneheaded mistake on my part. Thanks for your response. I really do appreciate it.